# What does 'length of assertion returned' mean on CAS JWT Service Ticket documentation?

Tags: jwt, cas

I am going through the documentation of CAS 5.2.X and I am planning to use JWT as service tickets.

It makes the below statement about expiration time of JWTs. I don't understand clearly what it means by '*length of assertion returned*' [here](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.2.x/installation/Configure-ServiceTicket-JWT.html#flow-diagram).

> The expiration time of the generated JWT is controlled by the length
>   of the assertion returned as part of the validation event. If the
>   assertion validity length is not specified, then the expiration time
>   is controlled by the length of the SSO session defined as part of SSO
>   expiration policy of the CAS server.

Is this a JSON term? I have heard about assertions in regards to testing. But I don't quite understand what this means here. Could anybody explain this please?

Answer (score 1):

This is trying to explain the expiration policy of the JWT and how it's calculated. In the diagram on that page, there is a step to validate an ST internally. This validation call produces an assertion for the JWT module based on which the JWT is built. If the assertion is configured to be valid for a specific length of time, that's qhat the JWT would use. Otherwise, the JWT would be valid for the length of the SSO session, established as part of SSO expiration policies.

Overall notes indirectly related to the flow:
https://apereo.github.io/2018/02/26/cas-delegation-protocols/